# Q: Help to understand the thought process of solving the probability trough conditional probability

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability

While studying for my statistics exam i stumbled over the following question:

"There was a warehouse that created bags with marbles in them, they filled all the bags until "enough" marbles was in them. Unfortunately "enough" was not always the same, instead the probability for a bag containing 14, 15 or 16 marbles was the same. Calculate the probability that a bag contains exactly 3 white marbles if the warehouse contains 10% white marbles."

I have no clue how to solve this and tried for a while but just ended up being more confused than i originally was. Is there anyone that can "slowly" explain the thought process of solving a problem like this?
I would assume that I need to use some conditional probability but can't really get anywhere with it.

Comment: What is the probability of exactly $3$ white marbles in a bag of $14$? in a bag of $15$? in a bag of $16$?  Then combine these results using  "the probability for a bag containing $14$, $15$ or $16$ marbles was the same"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Pr(\text{3 White}) = \Pr(\text{3 White}\mid \text{14 in bag})\Pr(\text{14 in bag}) + \Pr(\text{3 White}\mid \text{15 in bag})\Pr(\text{15 in bag})+\Pr(\text{3 White}\mid \text{16 in bag})\Pr(\text{16 in bag})$

Per the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).  If you insist on phrasing it that way, you can also imagine an invisible $\text{"}\mid \text{10% white in warehouse"}$ on every term as well, but it is unnecessary.

Each of these terms in the expansion on the right should be readily able to be calculated.

> $\Pr(\text{3 White}\mid\text{14 in bag})$ for instance you can use binomial distribution.  $\Pr(\text{14 in bag})$ is given to you in the problem statement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand the solution and it makes sense to me. But I dont understand how you so quickly understood to use the binomial distribution? Is it just a lot of practice and eventually you are able to see solutions like this?

Comment: @forsb Practice certainly has a lot to do with it, practice in writing problems, in reading problems, ... Part of the nuance here is that the warehouse is presumed to have "*many*" marbles... that it has enough marbles to produce thousands or tens of thousands of these bags.  In reality, the factory ought to have only finitely many marbles and so technically the color of the marbles as they are being placed into the bag should be dependent on one another... but with a sufficiently "*large*" population we are selecting from, assuming their color is independent is a "good enough" approximation.

Comment: If in reality the factory only had 50 marbles available, and so enough marbles to only make a few bags, then the approximation would not have been a good one and we should have used hypergeometric distribution instead.

Comment: Alright thanks again. I will try to look for some similar exercises and practice some. I find it quite difficult to think of the problem like you explained, but as you say it that has to do with some lack of experience and knowledge!